# How to override errorClass in Jquery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a code which is for validating correct input in text fields. Using Jquery, the system can validate correct or valid email address for example and an empty field. I display the error message in modal. In the same time to notify the user, the text fields are also coloring its border with color red using CSS.

The conflict is in displaying the error message in the modal, it is also having a color red border in the message. How can I remove this.

Here's the code

```
  $("#RoleConfigForm").validate({
        rules: {

            "group_code[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 25,
            },
            "role_name[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 25,
            },

            "email_address[]": {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 30,
                email: true,
            },
        },
        onkeyup: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        errorClass: "invalid",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $('#ResultDialog p').html(error);
            $('#ResultDialog').modal();
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            ajaxFormSubmit();
        }
    });

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
        required: "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_empty_fields",
        email: "@hmis_resources.Message.msg_invalid_email"
    });
```

css

```
 .invalid {
        border: 1px solid red !important;
    }
```

html of modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ResultDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-result" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><img src="/Content/images/close.png"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">HMIS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="ResultMsg">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="dialog_confirm_btn" data-dismiss="modal">@hmis_resources.Resource.btn_confirm</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: are you looking for custom error message rather than input valid email address

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: @NairAthul I am okay now with the modal and error message in it, just the unnecessary red border around jus like in the image

Comment: done @KaushikAndani please see edited

Answer (score 0):

Please update errorPlacement

with Below Code

```
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $('#ResultDialog p').html(error);
    $('#ResultDialog p').css('border','none');
    $('#ResultDialog').modal();
},
```

Comment: okay would you share your workable code with Snippet or jsfiddle so i can run, test and solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want the red border to go off on any error. Override the `.invalid` class with your desired style like:

```
.invalid{
  border: none !important;
}
```

This will not have any border at all for that invalid class element. You can also have the default style for the border on invalid class element like:

```
.invalid{
  border: inherit;
}
```

I hope it solves your problem